# Show an ASCII character

Tags: r, ascii

I want to show a block ASCII character █ (it's ASCII code is 219),

How can I show it in terminal?

I am using RGui on WinXP

Comment: Why? Are you trying to draw something? - just curious :)

Comment: if this results in anything other than a Space Invaders clone for R, I'm going to be disappointed.

Comment: I want to use it as a char parameter in a progress bar. ?txtProgressBar really sucks with a char = "¦"

Comment: There is no such thing as an ASCII code of 219. ASCII is defined for 7 bits (0..127). A character code of 219 would display as a platform-specific character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use backslash to escape otherwise unprintable characters:

```
print("\245")
```

displays the Yen character (<kbd>¥</kbd>) on my gui. The 245 is in octal format, so the above expression is printing out ASCII (or whatever encoding the GUI is using) character 165.

219 is 333 in octal, but

```
print("\333")
```

prints out the <kbd>Û</kbd> character on my gui.

---

A few (but by no means all) unicode characters are also supported on the R gui:

```
cyrillic_d <- "\u0414"
print(cyrillic_d)
```

outputs <kbd>Д</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Following mobrule, the following works on R running in a UTF-8 locale on Linux:

```
> "\u258A"
[1] "▊"
```

Comment: that looks pretty good in Win as well. Looks like an open rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Windows

```
> "\u2588"
[1] "█"
```